# How to create mac application, which will be always running in the background and collects Location?

Tags: macos, cocoa, launch, daemons

I need to know how to create an application which will always be running in the background and collects location info once every 10 minutes. I don't know much about launch agents and daemons.

I have read a few examples where I found Launch agents is just a plist file. Should we launch the app through launch agents every 10 minutes? How to do that?

Answer (score 3):

There's no simple answer to this; you really need to read—or at least familiarize yourself with—the [Daemons and Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLoginItems.html), particularly the "Creating Login Items" section.

If you plan on creating a sandboxed (App Store) application, that limits your options somewhat, but not dramatically (for this kind of application).

You need to decide if your background process needs a UI or not. I suspect not, so I'd direct you to the either the XPC Service or user agent route. These will be registered with `launchd` and `launchd` has about a billion different options for how and when your process gets launched, and one of those is periodically. For more info on those, see `man launchd.plist`, particularly `StartInterval` and `StartCalendarInterval`.

With this knowledge, I'd then suggest to do some internet and open source searches looking for examples. I'm sure you'll find plenty.

Comment: Can you please give any demo example how to make XPC service? how to connect to main app? Tracking location code will be in main cocoa app or XPC service? I don't have any idea about daemons and XPC

Comment: The tracking would be done by the background service (either a login item, user agent, or XPC Service). Read the first part of the guide ("Types of Background Processes") to decide which one fits your needs. (I'm now thinking a user agent is probably your best bet.) Once you decide the kind of service, follow the detailed, step-by-step, instructions in that section for creating your service. This is complicated stuff. I googled a couple of, very simple, example projects on GitHub; you should be able to do the same.